# Exercise related to vector fields, map degrees and Poincare-Hopf's Theorem

Tags: general-topology, geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, vector-fields

I got stuck with one exercise from Chapter 3.5 in Guillemin and Pollack's book, which I used to study differential topology by myself:

Given a vector field $\overrightarrow{v}$ with isolated zeros in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ and a compact $k$-dimensional submanifold $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^k$ with boundary. If $\overrightarrow{v}$ is never zero on the boundary $\partial W$, then we have that the sum of indices of $\overrightarrow{v}$ at its zeros inside $W$ equals the degree of the following map:

$$\frac{\overrightarrow{v}}{|\overrightarrow{v}|}: \partial W\rightarrow S^{k}$$

I have tried following the hint to delete (sufficiently small) balls around the zeros and follow the standard argument used to prove Poincare-Hopf's Theorem. It turns out that the manifold $W$ becomes a manifold with "two parts" of boundaries after we delete the balls: the original boundary $\partial W$ and the boundaries of the omitted the balls. I guess we just need to show that the degrees of the map $\frac{\overrightarrow{v}}{|\overrightarrow{v}|}$ on these two parts of boundaries sum up to zero, right? However, is there a way to consider the manifold $W$ as a whole to prove the claim?

Thanks in advance! Any hint/help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean “as a whole”? This is an immediate consequence of the Boundary Theorem.

Comment: Hi Ted, thank you so much for your hint! I guess "manifold $W$ as a whole" refers to the new manifold obtained after the balls around the zeros are deleted (so basically we get a new manifold whose boundaries consist of two parts- one part being the original boundary and the other part being the boundaries of the ball). May I ask what's the "Boundary Theorem" you mentioned here? It it seems that it's not on the book? Thanks again for your hint!

Comment: They definitely call it that and use it numerous times. Better read carefully.

Comment: Hi Ted, thank you again for your hint! I think I almost figured out the problem now. However, may I ask you one more dumb clarification question?

Comment: So basically by definition, the degree of a map $f:X \rightarrow Y$ can only be defined when $X$ and $Y$ have the same dimension, right? Here the normalized vector field $\frac{v}{|v|}$ maps $\partial W$ to the $k$-sphere $S^k$, where $\partial W$ is of dimension $k-1$ but $S^k$ is of dimension $k$. How can the degree of $\frac{v}{|v|}$ be defined appropriately on $\partial W$ when its dimension is fewer than that of $S^k$?

Comment: My bad Ted. I think it's a typo: it should be $S^{k-1}$ instead of $S^k$

Comment: Yes. That's a typo. I never assigned that particular exercise, so I hadn't caught it. [Here](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/users/user317/Guillemin_Pollack_errata.pdf) is a list of errata in Guillemin & Pollack that you might find useful.